# Is it possible to force cast an enum with an associated value to a variable whose type matches the associated value?

Tags: swift

I have this simple enum:

```swift
enum Value {
    case boolean(Bool)
    case number(Double)
    case string(String)
}
```

I'm writing a toy language interpreter and performance is important to me. Given this contrived snippet:

```swift
let d: Value = .number(1.2)
let stack: [Value] = [d]
```

I know that `stack[0]` is **definitely** a `.number` `Value` and I want to get its associated value (which is a `Double`). For the life of me I cannot figure out a way to do this that doesn't require a conditional check either with `if let` or `guard case`.

What I want to do is something like this (which is invalid):

```swift
let result: Double = (stack[0] as! Value.number)
```

I know this works:

```swift
guard case .number(let result) = stack[0] else {
 // Never happens because I **know** stack[0] is a .number
}
// Now I can use result.
```

I'm trying to avoid conditional checks when I know the type of Value present since this is occurring in a hot loop.

Comment: I think if performance is important, better to look at another language.

Comment: May be you just need: `let stask: [Any]`?

Comment: There's no branchless way to fetch an associated value out of an enum, as far as I know. Even `as!` wouldn't help, that's still doing a branch internally. You could probably manually fish it out with `unsafeBitCast`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be like that:

```
protocol Value {
}

extension Bool: Value {}
extension Double: Value {}
extension String: Value {}

let d: Double = 1.2
let stack: [Value] = [d]

let result = (stack[0] as! Double)
```